# Create table rows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and learn about querySelector(), createElement(), setAttribute and loop.
I try to create a table with a row, which contains 5 cells in it.

Imagine I create  in HTML file. I use following code to execute my idea:

```
// 1. select id = pixelCanvas and store in var table.
const table = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

// 2. create table row element <tr></tr> and append to var table.
table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

// 3. create element table data and store in var data.
const data = document.createElement('td');

// 4. set html attribute with class="cell", width: 20px & height: 20px for table data
data.setAttribute('style', 'width: 20px; height: 20px:');

// 5. use for loop and appendChild() to append 5 <td></td> to <tr></tr>
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let tblRow = document.querySelector('tr');
    tblRow.appendChild(data);
};
```

Here is the result in HTML page.

[image]

Obviously my idea doesn't work as expected. Appreciate your advice: where goes wrong?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close to working - you just need to create a seperate `td` element for each iteration of the for loop, and setting the style attribute is much easier when done via the `.style` property of the element.

Also instead of trying to query for the row you have just created, you can use the return value of the `createElement` function - it will give you the variable containing the new element.

See this snippet:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

const colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "purple"];

const row = document.createElement('tr');
table.appendChild(row);

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.style.width = "20px";
  cell.style.height = "20px";
  cell.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  row.appendChild(cell);
};
```

```html
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I know I must create element <td></td> in every loop and append it to row.

Answer (score 1):

prefer to use css to style attributes.
there is also js methods for tables :

- [HTMLTableElement.insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)
- [HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('table#pixelCanvas')

for (let r=0;r<5;++r) {
  let row = myTable.insertRow()
  for (c=0;c<5;++c) {
    row.insertCell().textContent = `${r}.${c}`
  }
}
```

```css
table#pixelCanvas {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 9px;
}
table#pixelCanvas td {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this

Move the row outside the loop and if you need the cells to be the same, clone the one you made - you also had a typo in it (colon instead of semicolon)

I would also target the tbody since a table should have such a thing

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas tbody');

const data = document.createElement('td');
data.setAttribute('style', 'width: 20px; height: 20px;');
let tblRow = document.createElement('tr');
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let cell = data.cloneNode(true)
  cell.textContent = i;
  tblRow.appendChild(cell);
}
table.appendChild(tblRow);
```

```html
<table id="pixelCanvas">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result

```html
<table id="pixelCanvas">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">0</td>
      <td style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">1</td>
      <td style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">2</td>
      <td style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">3</td>
      <td style="width: 20px; height: 20px;">4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```